# PowerShell: Subdirectory listing to a txt-file

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Today I started scripting in Windows PowerShell - so please excuse my "dumbness"...

I want to create txt-Files with the name of the subfolders of each "rootfolder" on drive G:. On G:\ I have the following folders:

1_data
2_IT_area
3_personal
4_apprenticeship
7_backup
8_archives
9_user_profile

So I wrote this script:

```
get-childitem G:\ | ForEach-Object -process {gci $_.fullName -R} | WHERE {$_.PSIsContainer} > T:\listing\fileListing+$_.Name+.txt
```

But the script isn't doing what I want - it's creating only one text file.. can u help me? I already tried it as described here >> http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/variables-arrays-hashes/  "T:\listing\$_.Name.txt" - doesn't work as well...

Thank u very much for your Help!

-Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Get-ChildItem G:\ | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
    Foreach {$filename = "T:\fileListing_$($_.Name).txt"; 
             Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse > $filename}
```

And if typing this interactively (using aliases):

```
gci G:\ | ?{$_.PSIsContainer} | %{$fn = "T:\fileListing_$($_.Name).txt"; 
                                  gci $_ -r > $fn}
```

The `$_` special variable is typically only valid within a scriptblock `{ ... }` either for a Foreach-Object, Where-Object, or any other pipeline related scriptblock. So the following filename construction `T:\listing\fileListing+$_.Name+.txt` isn't quite right.  Typically you would expand a variable inside a string like so:

```
$name = "John"
"His name is $name"
```

However when you're accessing a member of an object like with `$_.Name` then you need to be able to execute an expression within the string.  You can do that using the subexpression operator `$()` e.g.:

```
"T:\listing\fileListing_$($_.Name).txt"
```

All that filename string construction aside, you can't use `$_` outside a scriptblock. So you just move the filename construction inside the Foreach scriptblock.  Then create that file with the contents of the associated dir redirected to that filename - which will create the file.

Comment: Thank you so much! - explained super precisely :) thanks a lot!